# How to find out which express handler function will be called next?

Tags: express, middleware

Is there a way to check what is next middleware function in call stack in express application?

I've tried to check by comparing **next** function with the reference to function i surely know will be called next.

```
public static async requestMapper(request: Request, response: Response, next: Function){
    console.log(next == ExampleController.exampleHandler)
    next();
}
```

Even though I indeed know that ExampleController.exampleHandler is called next, output of this snippet is **false**

Comment: `next` isn’t *your* function, it’s an ExpressJS function—otherwise calling it with no arguments would mean no `req`/`res`/`next` params. What’s the specific usecase? In general it’s sus to need to know this at runtime since middleware order is determined at config time.

Answer (score 0):

From express [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) it's not possible to access to next middleware. Middleware functions can perform the following tasks:

- Execute any code.
- Make changes to the request and the response objects.
- End the request-response cycle.
- Call the next middleware function in the stack.

It's same for [nest.js](https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware)

I think you have bad approach if you try to understand which next middleware.